# What is a short-circuit proof cable?

Tags: cables, short-circuit, low-voltage, earth

German norms and standards (VDE 250 Teil 602) specify, that wires and cables, rated for 3kV can be considered as "short-circuit proof" and "earth-fault proof" in low-voltage installations (below 1000V). Typical cable of such kind is NSGAFÖU 1.8/3kV.
I don't find any reference to such cables in english-spoken community, as well as any reference to what is a short-circuit proof cable means at all.
So first question about "short-circuit proof" cable itself - Does it mean, that such cable can be connected without a fuse to more powerful circuit and in case of short-circuit it will just break gracefully, without any fire or insulation breakage, such as conventional wire would do? Is it protected from overload as well? Is there any EN/IEC standard specifying such application?
Second question (might be not related), but why 3kV cable is considered as "short-circuit proof" cable being used in LV installation? Just because of better insulation? Is there any IEC/EN norm allowing such use?

Comment: I expect that it means that a 3 kV rated cable designed and manufactured to a recognized quality standard can be used in systems where the peak voltage is less than 1,000 volts without fear of it developing an internal short-circuit.

Comment: (For me, "short-circuit proof" has the wrong connotations. I'd prefer *protected against ground faults and short circuits* as a translation.)